# Error when I run this command "fx set core.qemu-x64"

Tags: fuchsia

```
ERROR at //third_party/openssh-portable/fuchsia/developer-keys/BUILD.gn:10:24: Could not read file.
  manifest = read_file("//.fx-ssh-path", "list lines")
                       ^---------------
I resolved this to "/home/shivkumar/fuchsia_os/fuchsia/.fx-ssh-path".
See //products/core.gni:102:3: which caused the file to be included.
  "//third_party/openssh-portable/fuchsia/developer-keys:ssh_config",
  ^-----------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: error running gn gen: exit status 1
```

Comment: This sounds like it might be an issue with the local environment. Can you confirm that `fx-env.sh` was run according to the environment setup instructions? https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/get_fuchsia_source#set-up-environment-variables

Comment: I have sourced fx-env.sh file in .bashrc file.  like this                                                          
export PATH=~/fuchsia_os/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin:$PATH
source ~/fuchsia_os/fuchsia/scripts/fx-env.sh

Comment: @ShivkumarKonade there's an unofficial IRC Channel with fuchsia devs on the OFTC network. I would recommend you join #fuchsia on oftc during working hours to get someone to guide you through the setup process

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the `//.fx-ssh-path` file does not exist, or is otherwise unreadable. This file is typically generated on source checkout when the integration manifest runs `//tools/ssh-keys/gen-ssh-keys.sh` as a [jiri hook](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/integration/+/refs/heads/main/stem).

To correct the problem, use `gen-ssh-keys.sh` again to re-generate the file(s) before setting your build configuration:

```
$ tools/ssh-keys/gen-ssh-keys.sh
$ fx set core.qemu-x64
```

> **Note:** Hooks are also run anytime you run `jiri update` so you could also resync the source tree to correct the issue.

Comment: After tring this I got this error. ERROR at //src/connectivity/bluetooth/hci/vendor/atheros/BUILD.gn:6:1: Can't load input file.
import("//build/cipd.gni")
^------------------------
Unable to load:
  /home/shivkumar/fuchsia_os/fuchsia/build/cipd.gni
I also checked in the secondary tree for:
  /home/shivkumar/fuchsia_os/fuchsia/build/secondary/build/cipd.gni
See //src/connectivity/bluetooth/BUILD.gn:31:5: which caused the file to be included.
    "hci/vendor/atheros:driver",
    ^--------------------------
ERROR: error running gn gen: exit status 1

Comment: I believe that `//build/cipd.gni` is also generated as part of the prebuilts jiri hook. It sounds to me like your source checkout wasn't properly bootstrapped. I would recommend starting over with a fresh checkout following the instructions: https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/get_fuchsia_source